# Setting Permissions on files shared between Linux and Windows on EMC Celerra

Tags: windows, linux, permissions, emc

I have an EMC Celerra filesystem shared between Windows and Linux Clients.  User A on a Windows client creates a directory and set of files and User B on a Linux client is to modify and/or delete these files; however the files and directory to not have write permission for anyone other than the original owner.  If this was on a Linux NFS share, I could use umask to set the permissions to allow group write permissions.  Is there a way for the Windows client to set the correct permissions on the files when created?  Or is there a way to do this on the EMC Celerra?  I can write a script to perform a chmod on the Linux side but wanted to avoid this if possible.

Thank you,
JP20036

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but if you are managing the Celerra share via Windows you can set permissions there and you can set it so that any user has wright permissions pretty easily from the share creation wizard. Try recreating the share and coming at the permissions that way (obviously OP is no longer looking for an answer, but just in case anyone googles it).